# Magento 2 Passing php data to custom js component or file

Tags: magento2, javascript, ajax

I need to send ajax call on a button click in admin page. I want to send ajax url and record id from php to my js file in magento 2. How it can be done in standard way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can build magento urls in js component using mage/url as below ;

```
define(
    [
        'mage/url'
    ],
    function (urlBuilder) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
               template: 'VendorName_ModuleName/path/to/template'
            },

            yourFunction: function(){
                var url = urlBuilder.build("routename/controller/action");

            },
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi, It does not return full url, just returns 'routename/controller/action'

Comment: Use "Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder" instead of "mage/url"

Comment: @Neo,  "Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder" cannot be used everywhere, because storeCode: window.checkoutConfig.storeCode will be undefined on other pages except checkout processes.